# Inline random integer or file

Tags: command-line

I have a folder with a few files named `1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, ...`

Also, I have a command which accepts an mp3 file as an input:

```
blablabla -i mp3/1.mp3
```

I would like to pass to the command **random** mp3 file.

```
blablabla -i mp3/<random int in range 1-n>.mp3
```

Or

```
blablabla -i mp3/<get random file from mp3 folder>
```

I am looking for the simplest method to do it, it doesn't matter which one.
Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `blablabla -i mp3/$(( ( RANDOM % N )  + 1 )).mp3`

Replace `N` with Max number you want to generate, or `1` Min number.

Or you can use `$(shuf -i MIN-MAX -n 1)` instead.

from [`man shuf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/shuf.1.html):

```
-i, --input-range=LO-HI
    treat each number LO through HI as an input line
-n, --head-count=COUNT 
    output at most COUNT lines
```

Actually `-n 1` in `shuf` here means only generate one random Num, you can test with `-n 2` which is generating two Random Nums.

You may also wants to have this with `printf` if your files name has leading 0's.

```
printf "%03d.mp3\n" $(( (RANDOM % 100) + 1 ))
018.mp3
```